# What operator checks type but not value?

Tags: javascript

So I recently learned about == and === which have been helpful, but I was wondering if there was one like this but only for types. Like it checks if they're both numbers but it doesn't matter what number they are.

Comment: I don't believe there's a single operator for this.

Comment: isNaN() – Stands for “is Not a Number”, if variable is not a number, it return true, else return false

Comment: Do you need to compare specific object types, or is object == object good enough (or are you only checking primitives)?

Comment: guess `typeof` it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `typeof`

Ej:

```
var a = 1;
var b = '2';
var c = typeof b === typeof a; // c is false
```